# Proving that Kurtosis is bounded from below by skewness plus $1$

Tags: inequality, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable that has finite fourth moments, i.e. $X\in L^4$, and that has a non-zero variance, i.e. $\mathsf V(X)\neq0$. I want to prove that the *kurtosis* of $X$ is bounded from below by its *skewness* squared plus 1, i.e. that

$$\mathsf E\left(\left(\frac{X-\mathsf E(X)}{\sqrt{\mathsf V(X)}}\right)^4\right)\geq1+\mathsf E\left(\left(\frac{X-\mathsf E(X)}{\sqrt{\mathsf V(X)}}\right)^3\right)^2.$$

---

**My attempt.** If we multiply both sides with $V(X)^3$, it boils down to, where $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{L^p}$ denotes the [$L^p$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions),

$$\lVert X-\mathsf E(X)\rVert_{L^4}^4\lVert X-\mathsf E(X)\rVert_{L^2}^2\geq \lVert X-\mathsf E(X)\rVert_{L^2}^6+\lVert X-\mathsf E(X)\rVert_{L^3}^6.$$

The inequality is homogenous since both sides are of "$6$-th power", so I would expect that this is reducible to some known analytic inequality. Can somebody help me out on how to do that?

Comment: Wow, a prodigy.

Comment: @haidangel I‘m flattered 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inequality is sometimes called Pearson's inequality. See the following paper for proof and further references:

[SKEWNESS, KURTOSIS AND NEWTON’S INEQUALITY (SHARMA AND BHANDARI)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-45/issue-5/Skewness-kurtosis-and-Newtons-inequality/10.1216/RMJ-2015-45-5-1639.full)